# In what formats is the feed of Facebook pages available?

Tags: facebook, format, facebook-feed

Facebook pages have the [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) URL to get the updates, for example `http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=00000000000000&format=rss20`.

I see that there is a corresponding JSON version at `http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=00000000000000&format=json`.

What is the exact list of available formats?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formats supported are:

- RSS 2.0 ([rss20](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=rss20))
- JSON ([json](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=json))
- ATOM 1.0 ([atom10](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=atom10))

The links are the value for the 'format' needed to get that format feed - links are to the ['Facebook' page](https://www.facebook.com/facebook).

Comment: Note: this answer is now out of date - the JSON feed was removed on 2015-01-28 and the the other feeds are to be removed on 2015-06-23 - source: [Facebook Platform changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)